# Can I call a "function-like macro" in a header file from a CUDA __global__ function?

Tags: c, macros, cuda, gpgpu

This is part of my header file `aes_locl.h`:

```
.
.
# define SWAP(x) (_lrotl(x, 8) & 0x00ff00ff | _lrotr(x, 8) & 0xff00ff00) 
# define GETU32(p) SWAP(*((u32 *)(p))) 
# define PUTU32(ct, st) { *((u32 *)(ct)) = SWAP((st)); } 
.
.
```

Now from the `.cu` file I have declared a `__ global__` function and included the header file like this :

```
#include "aes_locl.h"
.....
__global__ void cudaEncryptKern(u32* _Te0, u32* _Te1, u32* _Te2, u32* _Te3, unsigned char* in, u32* rdk, unsigned long* length)
{
    u32 *rk = rdk;
    u32 s0, s1, s2, s3, t0, t1, t2, t3;

    s0 = GETU32(in + threadIdx.x*(i) ) ^ rk[0];
}
```

This leads me to the following error message:

> error: calling a host function from a __ device__/__ global__ function is only allowed in device emulation mode

I have sample code where the programmer calls the macro exactly in that way.

Can I call it in this way, or is this not possible at all? If it is not, I will appreciate some hints of what would be the best approach to rewrite the macros and assign the desired value to `S0`.

thank you very much in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hardware doesn't have a built-in rotate instruction, and so there is no intrinsic to expose it (you can't expose something that doesn't exist!).

It's fairly simple to implement with shifts and masks though, for example if x is 32-bits then to rotate left eight bits you can do:

```
((x << 8) | (x >> 24))
```

Where `x << 8` will push everything left eight bits (i.e. discarding the leftmost eight bits), `x >> 24` will push everything right twnty-four bits (i.e. discarding all but the leftmost eight bits), and bitwise ORing them together gives the result you need.

```
// # define SWAP(x) (_lrotl(x, 8) & 0x00ff00ff | _lrotr(x, 8) & 0xff00ff00)
# define SWAP(x) (((x << 8) | (x >> 24)) & 0x00ff00ff | ((x >> 8) | (x << 24)) & 0xff00ff00)
```

You could of course make this more efficient by recognising that the above is overkill:

```
# define SWAP(x) (((x & 0xff00ff00) >> 8) | ((x & 0x00ff00ff) << 8))
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is not the macros themselves - the compilation process used by `nvcc` for CUDA code runs the C preprocessor in the usual way and so using header files in this way should be fine. I believe the problem is in your calls to `_lrotl` and `_lrotr`.

You ought to be able to check that that is indeed the problem by temporarily removing those calls.

You should check the CUDA programming guide to see what functionality you need to replace those calls to run on the GPU.

Comment: Thank that's the problem indeed, if I remove these calls everything works fine now I just need to replace these functions for valid cuda functions I appreciate it!!!!

Comment: Exactly, the C preprocessor will treat macros exactly the same in host and device code. So the problem is that after processing, the device code is attempting to call a host function.

Answer (score 0):

The error says what the problem really is. You are calling a function/macro defined in another file (which belongs to the CPU code), from inside the CUDA function. This is impossible!

You cannot call CPU *functions/macros/code* from a GPU function.

You should put your definitions (does **_lrotl()** exist in CUDA?) inside the same file that will be compiled by **nvcc**.

Comment: Macros are fine, since the preprocessor just expands them out as you would expect. The problem in this case, as Edric has answered, is that the macro contains function calls and those *functions* are host only.